# Typescript fetching JSON object

Tags: html, css, json, angular, typescript

[image: Capture]

I have gone and got some data from a request and it should be returning it as a json object that i can pass to and use in some html, however when run

```
console.log(this.data);
```

I can also see it has 20 elements in the articles array but it returns undefined or null as seen when i run

```
console.log(this.data.__zone_symbol__value);
```

Any help in solving this issue will be greatly appreciated. :)

Edit in response to comment:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?' +
        'country=us&' +
        'apiKey=c6aecd1cd1de49edaca2544076713c45';
   this.Newsdata = this.FetchHeadlines(this.url);

   console.log(this.Newsdata);
   console.log(this.Newsdata.__zone_symbol__value);

}

get(url: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', url);

        req.onload = () => {
            if (req.status === 200) {
                resolve(req.response);
            } else {
                reject(Error(req.statusText));
            }
        };

        req.onerror = () => {
            reject(Error('Network Error'));
        };

        req.send();
    });
}

FetchHeadlines(url: string): Promise<any> {
    console.log("Entered FetchHeadlines");

    return this.get(url).then(JSON.parse).catch(error => {
        console.log('getJSON failed for', url, error);
        throw error;
    });
}
```

Comment: show your getting value method.I have to know what you are doing. Then easy to help you.

Comment: I have made an edit for you @KarnanMuthukumar

Comment: iam updated new way to achieve your scenario. Please try once and let me know.

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(this.Newsdata, null, 2));
should give you a more readable output to start.

Comment: @Dylan Anelezark I tryed your way made some changes its worked.let's try once and let me know.

Comment: You are using Angular... so use the Angular `HttpClient`: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @DylanAnlezark did you tried my answer it's working perfect tested.Try once if any error let me know.

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this one line `JSON.parse()` method every thing works fine.

First Way

```
private getCall() {
        let url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=c6aecd1cd1de49edaca2544076713c45";
        console.log("Entered FetchHeadlines");

        this.FetchHeadlines(url).then((response)=>{
            let Data=JSON.parse(response);
            console.log("Data",Data);
            console.log("Data1",Data.articles);

        })      
    }
    get(url: string): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open('GET', url);

            req.onload = () => {
                if (req.status === 200) {
                    resolve(req.response);
                } else {
                    reject(Error(req.statusText));
                }
            };

            req.onerror = () => {
                reject(Error('Network Error'));
            };

            req.send();
        });
    }

    FetchHeadlines(url:string): Promise<any> {
        console.log("Entered FetchHeadlines");

        return this.get(url).then().catch(error => {
            console.log('getJSON failed for', url, error);
            throw error;
        });
    }
```

worked perfect tested.
screenshot,
[image]

Second Way:-

```
  private getCall(){
        let url="https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=c6aecd1cd1de49edaca2544076713c45";
            console.log("Entered FetchHeadlines");

            this.http.get(url).subscribe((response)=>{
                console.log("Response1",response);
                console.log("Response2",response.json());   //here got json value you can assign value to variable.         
            })
    }
```

screenshot,

[image]

I hope its solve your problem First way.

Thanks,
Muthukumar

Comment: Response1 :
Response1 {"status":"ok","totalResults":20,"articles":[{"source":{"id":null,"name":"Nydailynews.com"},"author":"Kerry Burke, JOHN ANNESE, Rocco Parascandola","title":"Two more Trinitarios members in custody in Bronx machete slay of Les TEXT CONTINUES

Response 2:
getJSON failed for https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=c6aecd1cd1de49edaca2544076713c45 TypeError: response.json is not a function

Comment: ok just log this another line console.log("Articles",response.articles); you got value i think now assign your value to any variable for further use

Comment: Response1 undefined

Comment: please wait few minute